# T-SQL Procedure with Multiple Drop Tables and Select Intos

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have T-SQL with multiple drop table statements immediately followed by select into statements:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tst.test') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE tst.test
GO
SELECT *
INTO tst.test
FROM tst.red
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tst.test2') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE tst.test2
GO
SELECT *
INTO tst.test2
FROM tst.blue
WHERE @PARAM = 'COLOR'
```

I'm trying to wrap those statements with a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.testProc @PARAM AS VARCHAR(50)
AS
IF OBJECT_ID('tst.test') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE tst.test
GO
SELECT *
INTO tst.test
FROM tst.red
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tst.test2') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE tst.test2
GO
SELECT *
INTO tst.test2
FROM tst.blue
WHERE @PARAM = 'COLOR'
```

This results in two primary errors when I run the above code:

1. `There is already an object named`test`in the database`
2. `Must declare the scalar variable @PARAM`

How do I resolve these two issues? I thought the `GO` statements between each portion of the query would cause the `test` table to be dropped prior to it being created again. I tried dropping the table manually, then creating the stored procedure. But then after the stored procedure was executed, selecting from `test` resulted in `This table does not exist`

Is there an example somewhere of this type of code being included in a stored procedure?

Thank you for any insight you may have!

Comment: Tip: if you're using SQL Server 2016+ you can use `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <name>`

Comment: `GO` isn't actually T-SQL. Use `;` instead. Or `BEGIN...END` to separate batches or encapsulate multiple statements.

Comment: Still on 2012, but I'll keep that in mind if we ever make the jump!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `GO` commands. `GO` is not a T-SQL statement. It's a batch separator used by SQL tools to delimit batches of statements.

Due to the first `GO`, the proc is created, containing only the first `DROP TABLE`, and the remainder of the script is executed immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to remove the 'GO' statements from your code.  The 'GO' statements indicate a batch file separator to SQL Server (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go)).  Also, wrap your stored procedure code in a BEGIN...END block:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.testProc @PARAM AS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('tst.test') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE tst.test;

    SELECT *
    INTO tst.test
    FROM tst.red;

    IF OBJECT_ID('tst.test2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE tst.test2;

    SELECT *
    INTO tst.test2
    FROM tst.blue
    WHERE @PARAM = 'COLOR';
END
```

Finally, while not always necessary, as a best practice you should complete the SQL statements with a semicolon (;).  There are a few SQL statements that will produce unexpected results because, unknown to you, the logic may flow forward to the next statement (e.g. the [WITH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) common table expression).